# Getting error when trying to download DearPyGui in Python 3.10.0

Tags: python, dearpygui

I've been trying to download DearPyGui using the command `python3 -m pip install dearpygui` but I always get the error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement dearpygui (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for dearpygui
```

I'm using Python 3.10.0 in VSCode on my MacBook Pro M1. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

There are no prebuild wheels on PyPI for `dearpygui` that are compatible with Apples M1 chip.

However you can build the library from source, if you still want to use it.
Related bug report and linked build instructions here: https://github.com/hoffstadt/DearPyGui/issues/1410